# Building a Responsive and Centered SVG

Tags: svg

I'm building a horizontal line with circles in between, I would like to center the whole thing and also make it responsive,

Here's the Codepen link: https://codepen.io/nagshankar/pen/yLPyZdN

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <path class="line"  d="M 250 0 l 0 75"/>
        <path class="line"  d="M 250 75 l 0 75"/>
        <path class="line"  d="M 250 150 l 0 75"/>

       <circle class="marker" cx="250" cy="75" r="15" fill="red"/>
       <circle class="marker" cx="250" cy="150" r="15" fill="red"/>

   </svg>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a viewBox, The viewBox value is the same as the bounding box of the group of elements.

```js
console.log(g.getBBox())
```

```css
section{
  background-color:#999999;
  position:absolute;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
svg{width:50%;height:50%;background-color:yellow;display:block;margin:0 auto;}

.line{
  fill:none;
  stroke:green;
  stroke-width:6;
}
```

```html
<section>

<svg viewBox="235 0 30 225"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<g id="g">
  
   <path class="line"  d="M 250 0 l 0 75"/>
   <path class="line"  d="M 250 75 l 0 75"/>
   <path class="line"  d="M 250 150 l 0 75"/>
  
   <circle class="marker" cx="250" cy="75" r="15" fill="red"/>
   <circle class="marker" cx="250" cy="150" r="15" fill="red"/>
  
  </g>

  
</svg>
  
</section>
```

Comment: how do you calculate the bounding box value? i mean, the value for viewBox

Comment: you use getBBox() as I used it in the demo above.